# Vraptor @Put brings null objects

Tags: vraptor

I'm trying to update an object using the @Put instead of @Post
The problem is, if i try with @Put Vraptor won't bring me my User object, but if i do a Post it will, without the object i cant update it, and i don't want to be updating something with @Post...

My method is:

```
    @Post("/update/{id}")
    //@Put("/update/{id}")
    public void update(long id,@Valid User user){
        user.setId(id);
        validator.onErrorForwardTo(this).formUpdate(user);

        user = dao.update(user);

        result.redirectTo(this).formUpdate(user);
    }
```

I am able to achiev both, but when using **PUT** the `user` comes **null**.

btw, i'm submitting the form via javascript

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
@Put("/update/{user.id}")
public void update(@Valid User user){
    validator.onErrorForwardTo(this).formUpdate(user);
    user = dao.update(user);
    result.redirectTo(this).formUpdate(user);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i was able to do it with `@Post`, but i'm trying to do it with `@Put`, is it possible?